# Expected Identifier - C

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I am having an issue with structs. Before each function declaration I get an error about an identifier. Errors occur before 'typedef', 'coords stackCreate', and 'coords stackPush'

```
typedef struct coords * coordPtr
{
  int x = -1;
  int y = -1;
  struct coords * next;
};

coords stackCreate(int x, int y){
  coordPtr stack = malloc(sizeof(coords));
  stack->x = x;
  stack->y = y;
  return stack;
}

coords stackPush(int x, int y, coords stack){
stack->next = malloc(sizeof(coords));
stack->next->x = x;
stack->next->y = y;
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Well, you have that `typedef struct coords * coordPtr` --- that's definitely not correct C.

Comment: have you tried: 
typedef struct _coords
{
  int x = -1;
  int y = -1;
  struct _coords * next;
} coords;

Comment: This is a simple misunderstanding of C syntax: `* coordPtr` go after the body of the `struct`, not before it. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
typedef struct coords * coordPtr
{
  int x = -1;
  int y = -1;
  struct coords * next;
};
```

should be

```
typedef struct coords 
{
  int x;
  int y;
  struct coords * next;
} *coordPtr;
```

The type alias has to come last. Also you cannot provide default initializers in a struct declaration.

**EDIT:**

Also in your program, you make use of two type aliases:  `coords` and `coordPtr`. If you want to also use `coords`, you also need:

```
typedef struct coords coords;
```

Comment: I switched it and removed the default initializers and am still getting the same errors